# Comparative analysis of Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithms on Android?

Tags: android, fft, dft

Has anyone done a comparative analysis of Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithms on Android platform?

Which implementation is the fastest so far?

Comment: why was this down-voted? what is wrong with the question, why does it not meet the requirements of the FAQ? I'm really wondering...

Comment: I have no idea why was it downvoted, nor I understand the Dibya's  comment.

Comment: ...which in the meantime he removed.